# Proving properties in representation theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am studying module and trying to solve following problems:

Let $G$ be a group and $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n\geq 1$.  Any group homomorphism $\phi: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ determines a unique ring homomorphism $\Phi: \mathbb{C}[G]\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$, which makes $V$ into a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

> Show that a representation $\phi$ is irreducible if and only if the associated $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module $V$ is simple.
>
> Let $\phi: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a representation and let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Show that the map $\phi^A: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ defined by $\phi^A(g) = A\phi(g)A^{-1}$ is also a representation and that the $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module structures on $V$ determined by $\phi$ and $\phi^A$ are isomorphic.

Here is the related definitions:

1. The homomorphism $\phi$ is called a linear representation of $G$.
2. The representation $\phi$ is irreducible if there is no non-trivial proper subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $\phi(g)W=W$ for all $g\in G$.

Honestly, I don't know how to start the problem. Any thoughts on those problems would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: This boils down to the fact that the category of left $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules and the category of representations of $G$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @Slup Thanks very much for your comment. But I am not familiar with category. Could you elaborate little bit more?

Comment: Start by checking that every representation of $G$ gives you a unique left $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module and show that this gives a "bijective"  correspondence between representations and modules.

Comment: @Slup Thanks again:) How about the second part of my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that any subrepresentation of $\phi$ determines a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-submodule of $V$ and viceversa (in a one-to-one correspondance). Therefore, we conclude that $\phi$ is irreducible iff $V$ is a simple $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module. For the second part, observe that the maps $\Phi,\Phi_A \colon \mathbb{C}[G] \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are related by a ring homomorphism on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ determined by $A$, yielding isomorphic $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module structures.

I left some details for you. I can fill them if you find it necessary.

Comment: Thank you. But it would be great if you can fill the details. I am having trouble filling them.

Comment: Both $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module structures on $V$ are related by matrix conjugation.